# Order CPT results by user->display_name with only user->ID available

Tags: wordpress

I have a custom post type that stores a couple of user IDs in postmeta.

I need to sort this column in the admin post list (edit.php). The column sorts correctly by its postmeta user ID, but I am displaying the user.display_name as content in that column. I'm not sure how to construct the SQL clauses to make this happen.

```
add_filter( 'posts_clauses', array( $this, 'sort_post_clauses' ), 10, 2 );
function sort_post_clauses( $clauses, $query ) {

    //Join user table onto the postmeta table
    $clauses[ 'join' ] .= " LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->users} ON {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta.meta_value={$wpdb->users}.ID";
    $clauses[ 'orderby' ] = "{$wpdb->users}.display_name ";
    $clauses[ 'orderby' ] .= ( 'ASC' == strtoupper( $wp_query->get( 'order' ) ) ) ? 'ASC' : 'DESC';

}
```

The 'join' clause above is incorrect.

The postmeta column is named `_some_user_id`. I'm not sure how to form the join statement to get it available in the query.

I need the results sorted by user->display_name.